# Show that the series is absolutely convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series is
$$\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^n}{n(\ln(n))^3}$$
I tried the ratio test which did not do anything.  I also tried the root test which gave me
$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt[n]{n}\cdot (\ln(n)^3-n)}$$
which I don't think is right.  Is their another test I can do to confirm that this series is absolutely convergent?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you tried the ratio test and didn't work then you don't need to try with the roots test. It will not work either as it will not work comparing with geometric series. In your case you can try with the integral test.

Comment: but does the integral test determine absolute convergence? @Alamos

Comment: Apply it to the absolute values

Comment: Take the absolute value of each term. If I remember right, the Condensation Test is a really useful test on the series involving logs.

Comment: Do you know that $\sum1/n^{\alpha}$ is convergent whenever $\alpha>1$ and that if $\sum a_n$ is convergent and $0\leq b_n\leq a_n$ then $\sum b_n$ is convergent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Is $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln^3n} $$ convergent or divergent? (Alternating series test)

Is $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left |(-1)^n \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln^3n} \right |= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln^3n} $$  convergent or divergent (Integral test, let $u=\ln x \implies du=\frac{1}{x} dx$ ?

If the above summations are both convergent then $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln^3n} $$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Or you can do the ratio test which will give you an answer of 0 which is less than 1, and thus concluding that the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: I didn't notice that you put integral test.

Comment: Is showing that the series of absolute values converges enough to conclude that the original series converges absolutely, or do you have to show that the original series converges as well?

Comment: @Nescio: Do look at the **definition** of absolute convergence. Also, you should try to prove that absolute convergence implies convergence.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Integral Test}$

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n (\ln(n))^3} \ \ \ \text{converges} \iff \lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{2}^{R} \frac{1}{x(\ln(x))^3}\ \text{dx}\ \ \text{converges}$$

Let $u =\ln(x), du = \frac{1}{x} \ \text{dx}\ $ ... (go from here!)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Absolute convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
$$
is equivalent to convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|
$$
Thus, absolute convergence of the series given is equivalent to convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n\log(n)^3}
$$
A good test to try when logs are involved is the [Cauchy Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). This would mean testing whether
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\frac1{2^n(n\log(2))^3}
=\frac1{\log(2)^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}
$$
converges.